# How to keep rows of data when merging csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am merging some csv files into one big database. The different files all have similar but varying columns - i.e, some files an extra column compared to others - and i managed to create an outputted csv file with all the column names. However, after doing this, none of the data appeared. Below is my code:

```
inputs = ['data_file1.csv', 'data_file2.csv', 'data_file3.csv',
      'data_file4.csv', 'data_file5.csv', 'data_file6.csv',
      'data_file7.csv', 'data_file8.csv', 'data_file9.csv', 
      'data_file10.csv', 'data_file11.csv', 'data_file12.csv',
      'data_file13.csv', 'data_file14.csv', 'data_file15.csv',
      'data_file16.csv']  


fieldnames = []

for filename in inputs:
    with open(filename, "r", newline="") as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        headers = next(reader)
        for h in headers:
          if h not in fieldnames:
            fieldnames.append(h)

with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader() #this is the addition.       
    for filename in inputs:
        with open(filename, "r", newline="") as f_in:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)  # Uses the field names in this file
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

I tried the above code and no data is appearing, as you can see in this screenshot:[image]

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this? I've also tried making a large dataframe by creating a separate dataframe for each csv file, and merging them, but this created a database with doubled columns and had no rows again. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is your nesting in the final lines.  When the `with` statement ends, the file is closed, so the `reader` object becomes useless.  If you indent the final two lines twice, so they are inside the `with`, then it should work.

Comment: Ah okay thanks! I'll try fix it. I'm very new to Python so thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a new error now that says ValueError: 'dict contains fields not in fieldnames: None'.  Do you have any idea on why?

Comment: What that suggests is that some of your files do not have a header line, or have headers that are missing column names.  Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The data won't appear because you read the lines: `for line in reader:` outside the file reading loop: `with open(filename, "r", newline="") as f_in:`. Below is the code that should work.

```
inputs = ['data_file1.csv', 'data_file2.csv', 'data_file3.csv',
  'data_file4.csv', 'data_file5.csv', 'data_file6.csv',
  'data_file7.csv', 'data_file8.csv', 'data_file9.csv', 
  'data_file10.csv', 'data_file11.csv', 'data_file12.csv',
  'data_file13.csv', 'data_file14.csv', 'data_file15.csv',
  'data_file16.csv']  


fieldnames = []

for filename in inputs:
    with open(filename, "r", newline="") as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        headers = next(reader)
        for h in headers:
            if h not in fieldnames:
                fieldnames.append(h)

with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader() #this is the addition.       
    for filename in inputs:
        with open(filename, "r", newline="") as f_in:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)  # Uses the field names in this file
            for line in reader:
                writer.writerow(line)
```